# Issue with saving words to linked lists in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int priorityc;
    char *itemName;
    struct node *next;
} node;
node *head;

void save();
void printcontents();
int search(char *itemName);
int serve(char *itemName);
void load();
void inserted();
void deleted(char *itemName);

int main()
{
    load();
    printcontents();
    save();
}

void load()
{
    head = NULL;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("California.txt", "r");
    int tempPriority;
    char tempName[200];

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %d", tempName, &tempPriority) == 2)
    {
        //The issue seems to arise somewhere in the remaining code of the load function
        node *tempNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        tempNode->priorityc = tempPriority;
        tempNode->itemName = tempName;
        tempNode->next = head;
        head = tempNode;
        printf("%s\n", head->itemName);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s\n", head->itemName);
}

void printcontents()
{

    node *current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", current->itemName, current->priorityc);
        current=current->next;
    }
}

void save()
{
    FILE *fp;
    node *current = head;
    fp = fopen("California.txt", "w");
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", current->itemName, current->priorityc);
        current=current->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The input file aka California.txt is a simple notepad file with the following information.

```
Desktop-computer 100
Desktop-screen 100
Desktop-keyboard 100
TV-set 80
Audio-system 75
Bed 65
Night-table 65
Hibachi 35
```

After the save function all the numbers do make it through but the following is what the console prints out and what is rewritten on the California.txt file.

```
{°@u&0@ 35
{°@u&0@ 65
{°@u&0@ 65
{°@u&0@ 75
{°@u&0@ 80
{°@u&0@ 100
{°@u&0@ 100
{°@u&0@ 100
```

I tried to making char tempName (string found in load) into a pointer and running the function like that but then the console prints out and saves to california file.

```
Hibachi 35
Hibachi 65
Hibachi 65
Hibachi 75
Hibachi 80
Hibachi 100
Hibachi 100
Hibachi 100
```

I've really run into a dead end here and I can't figure out how to fix the problem, any advice would help. If it was working correctly it should print out the following to the console.

```
Hibachi 35
Night-table 65
Bed 65
Audio-system 75
TV-set 80
Desktop-keyboard 100
Desktop-screen 100
Desktop-computer 100
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714280/preventing-char-in-linked-list-from-changing

Answer (score 1):

Your `node` stores the names via the pointer

```
char *itemName;
```

However in `load()` you do not allocate memory for each node. You just point it to `tempName`, which is a local variable, so at the end of the function you end up with a dangling pointer. You need to allocate memory for each `itemName`, then use a function such as `strcpy` to copy the result into it.

Another option is to use a fix-length array instead, e.g.

```
char itemName[80];
```

then [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) into it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be under the false impression that your assignment statement:

```
tempNode->itemName = tempName;
```

copies the entire string from one place to another. In many other programming languages this may be the case; not so in C.

All this statement does, is copy the memory address of buffer `tempName` into the pointer variable `tempNode->itemName`. This is wrong in two ways.

1. By repeatedly doing this, eventually *all* nodes in your linked list have a reference to the same string buffer. This buffer is overwritten repeatedly; at the end, all that is left is the last line read from file. Whatever node you access, you will always see that same string.
2. `tempName` is an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable). Its memory is likely to be reclaimed as soon as the program flow leaves function `load`. The linked list keeps on referring to that memory afterwards. This is a major bug that leads to undefined behavior.

The solution is to duplicate the string. This is easy to do with function `strdup`. Just replace this line of code:

```
tempNode->itemName = tempName;
```

by:

```
tempNode->itemName = strdup(tempName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are saving the same pointer.

Look:

```
typedef struct node
{
 int priorityc;
 char *itemName; <= here you have pointer
 struct node *next;
} node;`
```

And,

`tempNode->itemName = tempName; <= and here you get always the same pointer, not the value`

Try use: `strcpy(tempNode->itemName, tempName);` and see if it works. ;)

Comment: It win't work unless you allocate memory to `tempNode->itemName`.